# Image Resolution problem in Button Resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 C# Net.

Scaling: Font

Net version: 4.7.2

Scaling on my Main Display is set to 150 percent.**

Problem is I'm using an image in my Button.

This is how it looks on my machine.  Notice the nice space between the image and the text.

[image: How it looks on my machine... good]

But on some users machines, depending on their resolution, the text gets pushed up into the image.  It get scrunched.

It's like the image in the Button does not resize.  I'm not sure if this is just a bug in VS or what.

This is how it can look on some users machines... notice how the text is pushed into the little image.

Click the link.

[image: How it looks on some users machines... bad]

My project is set to use Win 10 high DPI support, so that's the not the issue.

```
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
    <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
    <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="true" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
```

I've also set the text to use bottom align.

Any ideas on how to handle this in an easy, simple way?

I don't want to use a background image because the text is dynamic.

Comment: *My project is set to use Win 10 high DPI support*: meaning (in details)? -- What kind of Project is that (what GUI platform)? If it's WinForms, what is the Form scaling to? Font or DPI? Are you designing at 100% scale? -- *I'm using Visual Studio 2019 C# .Net*: what .Net version? -- Add the required information to your question, not in comments and add the related Tags.

Comment: *Are you designing at 100% scale?* - It appear you don't. Don't you receive a warning, from Visual Studio, about that? -- If you scale to Font, you have no Control over the appearance of your application in another machine, unless you have designed a very flexible UI (very hard and time consuming in WinForms). Scale to DPI and, if/when needed, adjust proportionally the Font and the size of the Controls that are affected. Some layout *helpers*, as the TableLayoutPanel and FlowLayoutPanel, can make this process less painful (until you get the hang of it, that is).